# Consider a single record, per id, in a group by

Tags: sql, group-by

#### Background

I have an SQL table with 4 columns:

- `id` -    varchar(50)
- `g1` -    varchar(50)
- `g2` -    varchar(50)
- `datetime` -  timestamp

I have this query:

```
SELECT g1,
       COUNT(DISTINCT id),
       SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT id)) OVER () AS total,
       (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS float) / SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT id)) OVER ()) AS share
FROM my_table
and g2 = 'start'
GROUP BY 1
order by share desc
```

This query was built to answer: **What is the distributions of `g1` value out of the users?**

#### Problem

Each `id` may have **multiple** records in the table. I wish to consider the earliest one. early means, the minimum `datetime` value.

## Example

#### Table

```
id    g1    g2      datetime
x1    a     start   2016-01-19 21:01:22
x1    c     start   2016-01-19 21:01:21
x2    b     start   2016-01-19 09:03:42
x1    a     start   2016-01-18 13:56:45
```

#### Actual query results

```
g1  count   total   share
a   2       4       0.5
b   1       4       0.25
c   1       4       0.25
```

we have 4 records, but I only want to consider two records:

```
x2    b     start   2016-01-19 09:03:42
x1    a     start   2016-01-18 13:56:45
```

which are the earliest records per `id`.

#### Expected query results

```
g1  count   total   share
a   1       2       0.5
b   1       2       0.5
```

#### Question

How do I consider only the earliest record, per `id`, in the `group by`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'm new in `SQL`. How do I retrieve that information? using `SQL Workbench/J`

Comment: That's typically identified by the driver you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying from `my_table` all the data although you only want to have the earliest date for an `id`. I assume `id` is the primary key in the table.

I suggest you define a view (or inline view) which queries only the earliest dates for the `id`'s and you use your query on that view instead of on *my_table*.

The view could be defined as so and would contain only `id`'s of earliest date:

```
select * from my_table a 
where a.datetime = (select min(z.datetime) from my_table z where a.id = z.id) and a.g2 = 'start'
```

You can define that as a view or use it directly inline as in:

```
SELECT g1,
       COUNT(DISTINCT id),
       SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT id)) OVER () AS total,
       (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS float) / SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT id)) OVER ()) AS share
FROM (select a.id, a.g1, a.g2, a.datetime from my_table a where a.datetime = (select min(z.datetime) from my_table z where a.id = z.id) and a.g2 = 'start')
GROUP BY 1
order by share desc
```

Comment: instead of `select a.id, a.g1, a.g2, a.datetime` can I `select *`?

Comment: I think so yes.

Comment: the condition `and g2 = 'start'` must be inserted to the inner `select`. Otherwise, you may get the earliest records that does not comply to the condition

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is your DBMS so here's a standard ANSI way to do this

```
SELECT T1.g1,
       COUNT(DISTINCT id),
       SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT id)) OVER () AS total,
       (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS float) / SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT id)) OVER ()) AS share
FROM my_table T1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT id, MIN(datetime) AS mindt
     FROM mytable 
     GROUP BY id
     ) T2 ON T1.datetime=t2.mindt AND T1.id=T2.id
and T1.g2 = 'start'
GROUP BY 1
order by share desc
```

It might be slow if you have a large table and `datetime` is not indexed.

Comment: `ERROR: column t2.datetime does not exist`. any idea?

Comment: I forgot to alias the MIN(datetime) in the nested query, recheck

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution which should work in SQL Server, and any database which supports CTE:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT t1.g1,
           COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, MIN(datetime) AS datetime
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY id
    ) t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id AND
           t1.datetime = t2.datetime
)

SELECT t.g1,
       t.count,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte) AS total,
       t.count / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte) AS share
FROM cte t
```

Comment: where `id` is consider in this query, please?

Comment: @idanshmu Sorry, I misread the question.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the below query.

```
;WITH cte_1
   as (SELECT id, MIN(datetime) AS [Date]
     FROM YourTable 
     GROUP BY id
     ) 
     SELECT yt.g1,
            COUNT(DISTINCT yt.id) [Count],
            SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT yt.id)) OVER () AS total,
            (CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT yt.id) AS float) / SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT yt.id)) OVER ()) AS share
     FROM cte_1 c
       JOIN YourTable  yt
      ON yt.[datetime]=c.[Date] AND yt.id=c.id
and yt.g2 = 'start'
GROUP BY yt.g1
ORDER BY share DESC
```

Output :

[image]